# I cannot set breakpoint in CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda, nsight

I'm new to NSIGHT and CUDA. I tried to set a breakpoint inside my CUDA kernel code, but I can't--the breakpoint is set at the end of my kernel and not on the particular line I want to debug.

- I'm using VS2010 (MFC project) with NSIGHT 2.2 and CUDA 4.2.
- I'm compiling in debug mode.
- I'm using CUDA in a project which is not the "StratUp project".
- I'm using "Generate Host Debug Information" with "Yes (-g)"
- I'm using "Generate Device Debug Information" with "Yes (-G)"

I am currently running the program through *Menu->Nsight->Start CUDA debugging*.
When I try to set a breakpoint on a different project (which is "StartUp project"), i do succeed.
Any suggestions about how I can get the breakpoint to act on a particular line, versus the entire kernel?

Comment: idoo The procedures you specified work fine for me on the SDK samples. If you execute Debug > Break All after you launch the application and open the CUDA Info window (Nsight > CUDA Info > CUDA Info 1) and set the drop down in the top of the tool window to Modules do you see a valid module? Are you able to hit breakpoints in one of the CUDA SDK samples?

Comment: are you compiling with device debug information? (the -G option to nvcc)

Comment: Yes, I do . I'm using "Generate Host Debug Information" with "Yes (-g)".  I'm using "Generate Device Debug Information" with "Yes (-G)"

Comment: @GregSmith 1. i do see the kernel function in Cuda Info 1 under Modules. 2. I'm able to set breakpoint in a different projetc.

Comment: Any chance you are using your gpu for display? I don't believe you can debug a gpu if its also actively rendering your display.

Comment: @lmortenson starting with Nsight VSE 2.2 we do support local debugging on a single GPU

Comment: @idoo what is your driver version and GPU?  what is your StartUp project type (another vcxproj)?  Sounds like you have CUDA code on both projects, the non-StartUp and the StartUp project, but can not hit bp on the non-Startup project.  Are you able to actually build the non-Startup project, and can you verify that the file (.cu?) that has the CUDA code and where you want to set the breakpoint is being built with GPU debug info by right clicking on it and looking at the properties?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used too many threads (256X256) to activate my kernel.
    dim3 threads(256,256)
    (kernel<<<...,threads>>>

Answer (score -3):

It is important to note that when debugging CUDA, breakpoints set in device code will not work properly if the number of cores on your machine is greater than the number of CUDA threads being run. Additionally, if the number of CUDA threads is not evenly divisible by the number of cores, some cores will not hit device code breakpoints on the last iteration.

Comment: Really, what are your sources?